# uploading full directories from app root to S3 using laravel filesystem?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, laravel-5

It is possible to do the following code snippet but using Laravel filesystem?

```
        try {
            $s3 = AWS::createClient( 's3' );
            $s3->uploadDirectory( env('AMAZON_LOCATION'), env('AMAZON_BUCKET'), $this->key_prefix, [
                'params'      => [ 'ACL' => 'public-read'],
                'concurrency' => 20,
                'debug'       => true
            ] );
        }catch (S3Exception $e){

        }
```

I just don't feel like using a package more, but I cant manage to replicate the same functions with laravel file system, has anyone done it before or have a good pointer on how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only possible solution that I could come out with was the following:

```
            $files = File::files('/directory/path') );
            if ( sizeof( $files ) > 0 ) {
                $disk = Storage::disk( 'api_s3' );
                foreach ( $files as $file ) {
                    $path_info = pathinfo( $file );
                    $file_name = $path_info[ 'filename' ] . '.' . $path_info[ 'extension' ];
                    $disk->put( $file_name, file_get_contents( $file ) );
                }
            }
```

Is not the best solution ever, but it does work.